# Liquibase can't read UTF-8 from sql script

Tags: maven, plugins, liquibase

I'm trying to rollback liquidbase update with command like

```
mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackCount=1 -Dliquibase.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dictionary -Dliquibase.username=user -Dliquibase.password=Pass123 -Dli
quibase.changeLogFile=db/migration/liquibase-changeLog.xml
```

in liquibase-changeLog.xml file i have somethng like following:

```
<rollback>
            <sqlFile path="db/migration/U9__RBScript1.sql" stripComments="false"/>
            <sqlFile path="db/migration/V4__UpdateScript1.sql" stripComments="false"/>
        </rollback>
```

in V4__UpdateScript1.sql file i have something like following:

```
update dictionary

    set name = 'кириллица' where name = 'cyrillic';
```

in result in updated columns i have `РџРђРЎРџРћР Рў Р РћРЎРЎР�Р`
How to set up liquibase to read utf-8 symbols correctly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try editing liquibase.bat file by adding UTF-8 line.

`IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_OPTS set JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

[image]